# How to use python automation in flutter app?

Tags: python, android, flutter, automation

Can you please tell me how can I integrate the python automation in my flutter app. Such that suppose I have a text field and I have entered a youtube channel name. Then the app will automatically go to that channel and play the latest video for me as we do in desktops using selenium.

Yes, something like that. Also, I want to perform many such tasks using python automation. Please tell me if you have any reference links or knowledge regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever data you have automated in Python, you can expose as an API in Flask, then make HTTP requests to that endpoint from your Flutter app.

Comment: Okay, please provide a link of any source so that I can understand in much better way.

Comment: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask